# Duplicated Data When Joining 4 Tables in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 4 tables, with the relevant columns summarized here:

```
customers:
  id
  name

credits:
  id
  customer_id   # ie customers.id
  amount

sales:
  id
  customer_id  # ie customers.id

sales_items:
  id
  sale_id      # ie sales.id
  price
  discount
```

The idea is that `customers` lists all of our customers, `credits` lists each time they have paid us, `sales` lists each time they have bought things from us (but not what things they bought) and `sales_items` lists all of the items they bought at each of those sales.  So you can see that `credits` and `sales` both relate back to `customers`, but `sales_items` only relates back to `sales`.

As an example dataset, consider:

```
customers:
  id  |  name
  5   |  Carter

credits:
  id  |  customer_id  |  amount
  1   |  5            |  100

sales:
  id  |  customer_id 
  3   |  5

sales_items:
  id  |  sale_id  |  price  |  discount
  7   |  3        |  5      |  0
  8   |  3        |  0      |  0
  9   |  3        |  10     |  0
```

I have tried this in MySQL:

```
SELECT c.*,
  SUM( cr.amount ) AS paid,
  SUM( i.price + i.discount ) AS bought 
FROM customers AS c
LEFT JOIN sales       AS s  ON s.customer_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN sales_items AS i  ON i.sale_id = s.id
LEFT JOIN credits     AS cr ON cr.customer_id = c.id
WHERE c.id = 5
```

But it returns:

```
  id  |  name    |  paid  |  bought
  5   |  Carter  |  300   |  15
```

If I omit the `SUM()` functions, it returns:

```
  id  |  name    |  paid  |  bought
  5   |  Carter  |  100   |  5
  5   |  Carter  |  100   |  0
  5   |  Carter  |  100   |  15
```

So it looks like it's returning one row for every record matched in `sales_items`, but it's filling in the `amount` column with same value from `credits` each time.  I see that this is happening, but I'm not understanding why it's happening.

So, two questions:
**1.** What is happening that it's smearing that one value through all of the rows?
**2.** What SQL can I throw at MySQL so that I can get this back:

```
id  |  name    |  paid  |  bought
5   |  Carter  |  100   |  15
```

I know that I could break it all up in subqueries, but is there a away to do it just with joins?  I was hoping to learn a thing or two about joins as I tackled this problem.  Thank you.

**Edit:** I created an SQL Fiddle for this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0051b/1/0

Comment: @barmar you flag this question as a duplicate, but the link you provided doesn't match this situation and doesn't provide any explanation about **why** the duplicate values are coming through.  Also, the solution you posted uses lots of subqueries while I was hoping to see if this could be solved just with joins.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
SELECT c.*,( SELECT SUM( cr.amount ) FROM customer  c INNER JOIN credits cr ON  
 cr.customer_id = c.id WHERE c.id = 5 GROUP BY cr.id ) AS paid
,SUM( i.price + i.discount ) AS bought  
FROM customers AS c INNER JOIN sales s  ON s.customer_id = c.id 
INNER JOIN sales_items i  ON i.sale_id = s.id 
INNER JOIN credits cr ON cr.customer_id = c.id 
WHERE c.id = 5 GROUP BY s.id,cr.id
```

Comment: I don't believe that this solves the problem.  It seems to return the same results as the original SQL posted in the question.  See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0051b/2/0

Comment: here i use group by with customer and sales hence it calculates sum accordingly

Comment: Yes, I see the changes you made (`INNER JOIN` and `GROUP BY`) but I'm saying (check the link) is that it doesn't give different results from what I originally had.

Comment: i am not sure but above result is 5  |  Carter  |  300   |  15 and my result may be like 5   |  Carter  |  100   |  15

Comment: I am confused.  When I run your SQL on the data, it returns `5 | Carter | 300 | 15`.  I am using MySQL.  What are you using?

Comment: sorry i have not run this query .just i have predict

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45714/discussion-between-yograj-sudewad-and-clayton)

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct (c.id, c.name), sum(i.price+i.discount) AS bought, cr.amount AS paid
from customer c, credits cr, sales s, sales_items i
where s.customer_id = c.id
and i.sale_id = s.id
and cr.customer_id = c.id and c.id = 5
group by c.id, c.name;
```

I'm not very sure, but try this. Use group by; that is surely the solution.

Comment: Using `distinct` in a query obscures the logic of the query that would otherwise be in plain site through `group by`s and proper joining (left, right, outer, inner) and should be avoided in complex queries such as this (`select distinct age from people` is perfectly valid though).